# How to save a user's state in a whatsapp chatbot flow in cloud api

Tags: bots, chatbot, whatsapp, whatsapi, whatsapp-cloud-api

I'm trying to create a WhatsApp chatbot in the Meta cloud api (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/) where we would have a flow similar to  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yI93.png) (several options for the user to select).

Considering that I'm receiving messages on my backend, what would be the best way to know which stage of the bot the customer is in?
Is there any tool within the API itself or externally that would solve the problem? Would it be advisable to store this information in the database?